# Removing nested double quotes from within a json string (Twitter data)

Tags: python, json, string, twitter, quotes

I have the following problem with nested quotes within a string:

As part of a json block, there are often strings which themselves contain double quotes, which is the only string limiter allowed in json. I am talking about something like this (as an excerpt, there are actually many more elements to the json block):

```
{"truncated": false,
"source": "u003Ca href="http: //mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow"u003EMobile Webu003C/au003E",
"id_str": "177386775671615488",
"geo": null}
```

I am trying to parse this json block in Python. Obviously, due to the extra double quotes within the value of "source", the json formatting gets messed up.

Unfortunately, these messed up strings are used-entered, so I cannot just go back to the source and tell it to give me proper json data. Some real person once entered a string containing double quotes and this string now appears as a string delimited with double quotes in my json data. The data is actually from the Twitter API, maybe somebody has had similar problems or experience with that. I can hardly imagine that Twitter allows this or doesn't have a mechanism in place to prevent its json from getting destroyed.

**My question is now:** How can I remove the extra double quotes within a string such that my json doesn't get destroyed? I actually don't need the data in these strings, I need a different part of the json block. So if there is a smart way to just remove them entirely, that would be perfect. Unfortunately the extra double quotes appear in all kinds of different places, so I cannot use some kind of "removing the outermost quotes only" kind of mechanism nor can I remove all double quotes because in most places they are part of the json syntax. Is there maybe a smart RE-way of doing this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That is *not* valid JSON. To be valid, the `"` quotes need to be escaped to `\"`.

Comment: Are you certain that that is what the Twitter API is producing? I have not seen Twitter produce incorrect JSON like that before.

Comment: I see that you are missing *other* backslashes too. The `u003C` at the start should have been `\u003C` instead, for example. There are `u003E` characters in the sample too. Whatever produced this, *completely broke things*.

Comment: This is Twitter data indeed, but you are right, it almost appears like the "\" have gotten lost somewhere along the way. I really hope this isn't the core of it because I might have a lot of messed-up data lying around here...

Comment: How are you obtaining this data, perhaps we can help unscrew this?

Comment: Someone else is gathering and storing this data for me as compressed .xz and .bz2 files. I have an extractor script that is decompressing these files and copying relevant data into a plain json file for me. This worked fine when I tested it locally with some test data, but I suspect something is going wrong when I am running the extractor on the server where the data is stored. I need to talk to those people and will get back once I get more info...